# Select col1 as a, col1 as b from table having b=a+"s"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains a column of words. I want to check if there exists 
two words (a and b) where b=a+"s" (b has an extra 's' at the end for example word and words.)

Not quite sure what is the problem with my query.
I appreciate any helps

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dimitris posted, you will need to join the table to itself. *This can be quite an expensive operation*, so use with care.

```
SELECT a.col1
FROM tblname a
JOIN tblname b
  ON b.col1 = CONCAT(a.col1, 's')
```

Notice that `+` is purely for addition in MySQL. To concatenate strings, use the `CONCAT` function.

Comment: that was what I needed mate, I just changed the ouput to: a.col1 ,b.col1.

Answer (score 0):

You should cross join the table with itself to get all the word combinations like this:

```
SELECT a.col1,b.col1
FROM table a, table b
WHERE b.col1=a.col1+'s'
```

Comment: How do you think `word = words` going to return?